# In SQLite, how to prevent REPLACE from updating the id of an existing record?

Tags: sqlite, insert, replace

This is a basic example. An sqlite file stores kvps for a single project file:

```
CREATE TABLE settings (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,rel,key,val)
```

With `rel` usually being linked to `id`s on existing records but without any specific constraints.

This settings table holds settings such as `key=name, value=Josh` and `key=url, value=www.site.com`, so on. The sqlite implementation which I'm using ignores multiple queries in an execution, and looping is slow, so I'm left with doing something like this:

```
REPLACE INTO settings(key, val) 
    SELECT 'name', 'Vosh' UNION SELECT 'url', 'www.site.com' UNION ...
```

This would normally update `Josh`'s name to be `Vosh` but it also sets a new id, thus breaking any relationships held between that particular record's id, referenced by `rel` in another row.

How should I approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by looping is slow? Each query is slow to execute?

Comment: The query execution function logs to a file, then broadcasts the output along with query to a console (which robs 100-200 more ms). I'm trying to implement this mechanism into additional modules which will store complex diagram relations into tables, worth of thousands of records.

Comment: just to be sure, do you run these updates in separate transactions?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I don't have any `BEGIN` statements.

Comment: Then by default you _are_ running 1 transaction per update. Did you precisely time each instruction?

Comment: There's no problem with the instructions, I'm just trying to dodge multiple `DB.execute("INSERT -> UPDATE"); ` calls, because that `DB.execute()` is the one causing delays, not the execution.

Comment: yes I know I'm steering away from your "real" question; in any case just have a quick look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209438/sqlite-end-transaction-is-taking-too-long/10210627#10210627